# Subset vector by value and corresponding name

Tags: r, vector, subset

I have two named vectors. The first (`foo`) is a lookup vector. The second (`bar`) holds values that are generated in each run of a simulation. In a run, `bar` might not be the same length as `foo` and return different values for the same name and in random order; hence the two values for `b`, and `z` and `a` are in positions 1 and 4, respectively.

How can one subset `bar` so that it returns the values not in `foo` with the corresponding names? The desired output can be seen with `bar2`.

```
foo <- c(a = 5, b = 5, c = 5, d = 4, e = 5, z = 5) # lookup vector
bar <- c(z = 5, b = 4, b = 3, a = 5, e = 2)        # data

bar2 <- c(b = 4, b = 3, e = 2)                     # desired output

> bar2
b b e 
4 3 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could combine names and values:

```
bar[!paste0(bar, names(bar)) %in% paste0(foo, names(foo))]

#b b e 
#4 3 2
```

Answer (score 1):

One way using `mapply` :

```
bar[mapply(function(x, y) !any(names(foo) %in% x & foo %in% y), names(bar), bar)]

#b b e 
#4 3 2
```

Similar logic with `purrr`'s `imap_lgl`.

```
bar[purrr::imap_lgl(bar, ~!any(foo %in% .x & names(foo) %in% .y))]
```